# Discrete Fourier Transform error depencency from number of Fourier modes

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I have got a discrete input signal of length $N$, purely real. Is there any research on how the DFT and inverse DFT results depend on number of Fourier modes? I mean, function of number of frequencies showing the error between real input and recreated signal after DFT by inverse DFT.

If the sequence of DFT coefficients can be calculated as follows:

$$X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_n\cdot e^{-\frac{i2\pi}{N}kn}$$

then what is the dependency of error between input signal and signal recreated by inverse DFT and total number $k$ of coefficients?

Comment: Marina, using $N$ for naturals and $X$ for matrices is confusing

Comment: I do not understand your question.  The IDFT should be exact.  There should be no reconstruction error. Which error are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

If there is a research on this, it must have been done long time ago because the knowledge is almost mainstream in the industry now.

**Parseval's Theorem**

The input signal is given by linear combination of orthogonal basis:

$$
x_{n} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} X_{k} \cdot e^{\frac{i2\pi}{N}kn}
$$

The sum of squares of the input signal's elements is given by the following expression:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \|x_{n}\|_{2}^{2}
=
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \|X_{k}\|_{2}^{2}
$$

**Truncated DFT Result**

Suppose you approximate the discrete input signal using only the first $m$ coefficients:

$$
\hat{x}_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}X_{k}\cdot e^{\frac{i2\pi}{N}kn}
$$

The error is then given by the following:

$$
x_{n}-\hat{x}_{n}=\sum_{k=m}^{N-1}X_{k}\cdot e^{\frac{i2\pi}{N}kn}
$$

and the sum of squared error is given by (using Parseval's theorem):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \|x_{n}-\hat{x}_{n}\|_{2}^{2}
=
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=m}^{N-1} \|X_{k}\|_{2}^{2}
$$

**Remarks**

As you add more and more coefficient, the error may not necessarily decrease but cannot increase. However, the error also depends on which coefficients you use i.e. using the first $m$ coefficients may give you lower or higher error compared to if you use the last $m$ coefficients, although the number of coefficients used is the same.

Discrete Fourier transform is nothing more than decomposition of input vector (the input signal) into a linear combination of orthogonal basis. Unfortunately, in many engineering schools, connection between DFT and linear algebra is not taught properly.